# How much new plug in affects the UI of existing website in case of wordpress platform?

Tags: css, wordpress, user-interface, plugins, customization

I wanted to know up to what extent the plugin affects the UI of existing website in case of WordPress.
Ex.I have my business website.I want extend that website with some more features, such features for which plugin installation is necessary and that plugin also generates some more pages as per the plug in feature.

Answer (score 0):

New plugins are not affect your Existing UI. If the plugins have styling feature like AG Custom admin or Blue Admin than this will affected to your UI, otherwise plugins are not affected to your UI. You can add plugins without any hesitation.

Comment: I have experience of Plug in installation side-effects on UI of existing website if the Platform is Wordpress.Provide your views for the same.